# SQL query to find locations with department names as well as locations without departments

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across the following SQL question about the famous `HR` schema which ships with Oracle:

> Write a SQL query to find all the locations and the departments for each location along with the locations that do not have department. Don't use OUTER JOIN.

With `OUTER JOIN` it is easy:

```
SELECT department_name, city 
FROM locations
LEFT OUTER JOIN departments USING (location_id);
```

I get 43 results. I tried with this:

```
SELECT department_name, city 
FROM locations l, departments d
WHERE l.location_id = d.location_id OR 
      l.location_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM departments);
```

[image]

but I get only 27 rows as if I do:

```
SELECT department_name, city  
FROM locations 
JOIN departments USING (location_id);
```

Why does the `OR` not work? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @mathguy, I had a department with `NULL` in the `location_id` column in the `departments` table. That is why the `NOT IN` returns no row. Otherwise I would have many more rows looking for the location id from the `departments` table.

Comment: Probably the bad query is the first one, not the second..Left outer join should use ON, not USING

Comment: @Massimo, why? It does produce the desired results.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2107296

Comment: @Massimo read further down "Because the column names in this example are the same in both tables in the join, you can also use the common column feature by specifying the USING clause of the join syntax."

Comment: You're right, i did'nt know...i'm linked to 'traditional' sql

Comment: Are you sure about the number of rows from the second query (the one that's wrong)? I get 43 rows from the first query and 27 from the last query, just like you said - but from the middle one I don't get 27, I get **459** rows. Please double-check (I simply copied your query and pasted in my copy of Oracle, logged in as `hr`, so I don't think it's on my end).

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I am absolutely sure. The copy of my `HR` schema is pretty much unchanged so I doubt the problem is from corrupt data.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov - will you do me a favor and try, anyway? Or would you like me to explain why that's not possible first? It would be a lot easier if you would just copy and paste what you posted, and try. I have no doubt the table is OK; I don't believe THAT QUERY returns only 27 results.

Comment: @mathguy, I will do an update with a screenshot. But basically I really do copy and paste.

Comment: Hint: When `location_id` is NOT IN (...), and there are 16 of those, the WHERE condition is satisfied, so you get at least one row for each pair (department, city of such location_id).

Comment: OK, I see the screenshot, but that is really odd. With your second query you should get 27 rows from the match, PLUS 16 * 27 rows for the cities whose location_id is NOT in the departments table. Where did those rows go?

Comment: You may want to check the DEPARTMENTS table - do you have a department with NULL in the location_id column? That would explain the difference; if you have a NULL in the NOT IN (...) list, then the NOT IN condition returns no rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `city, department_name` from the inner join, then `union all` like so:

```
select city, department_name 
  from <inner join>
union all
select city, NULL
  from locations
 where location_id not in (select location_id from departments);
```

The second branch of `union all` will give you the 16 cities with no departments located there.

NOTE: The `NOT IN` condition will not work if there are departments with `NULL` in the `location_id` column. If that is possible, the condition can be altered to `not in (select location_id from departments where location_id is not null)`.

Comment: Hmm, `select city, NULL from locations where location_id not in (select location_id from departments);` returns 0 rows.

Comment: It must be the same problem: you must have a department with NULL for location_id. This (I mean your copy) is not the standard HR schema.

Comment: Yes. I do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or the HR schema changed between versions of Oracle (I have 12.1) but I doubt it.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov - I edited the answer to explain how to modify the NOT IN  condition in case there may be NULLs in that column.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select l.city, d.department_name from locations l, departments d
 where l.location_id=d.location_id
 UNION
 select l2.city, null department_name
 from locations l2
where not exists (select 1 from depertments d2 where   d2.location_id=l2.location_id)
```

Comment: This works even though it looks quite complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT l.*,
       (SELECT d.department_name
        FROM departments d
        WHERE d.location_id = l.location_id
       ) as department_name
FROM locations l;
```

If there is a concern about multiple departments in a location, then just aggregate them together:

```
SELECT l.*,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(d.department_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.department_name) as department_names
        FROM departments d
        WHERE d.location_id = l.location_id
       ) as department_name
FROM locations l;
```

Comment: This won't work because there might be more than one department in a location thus returning multiple rows from the subquery.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov A join is going to return multiple rows as well? This shows you how to write the query without an OUTER JOIN, I've explained why the OR didn't work in my answer. I don't believe they're looking for you to use implicit syntax.

Comment: Have you tried it? It returns `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: I like the use of `LISTAGG`. I would never think of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well It's simple if you try to imagane some intermediate steps:

lets imagane cross join of table and after it filter the result with your where clause. In that rowset not any rows with not null locations and null departments will be presented. You may prove it with next query:

```
SELECT department_name, city 
FROM locations l, departments d
WHERE d.location_id is null;

no row selected
```

But you specify `l.location_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM departments);`. This condition not influent to cross join between table.
Because of it you should get extra rows for loction without departments.

And thats why you need `left join` or `union` clause.